# Azure Container Apps - App with multiple containers - azure cli command

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-apps

I am using **Azure Container Apps** to host our Containers. I want one instance of an Azure Container App to host two different containers (these are services that share a similar lifecycle). This is possible to do manually via the Azure portal, but I cannot see a way to automate it via the Azure CLI.

I have been using the `az containerapp up` CLI command to create an App with a single container.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-up

But is there a way with the CLI to create an app that manages 2 containers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **az containerapp compose create** command let you specify a Compose file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/compose?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: Wouldn't that create multiple ACAs under the Azure Container Environment?